# overlay filter with simple PNG adds black fringe

Tags: ffmpeg

Trying a simple overlay example, getting nasty black fringes:

```
fmpeg -y -i b.png -i a.png -filter_complex "[0:v]format=rgba[a];
    [1:v]format=rgba[b];
    [a][b]overlay,format=rgba"  normal.png
```

[image: b]
[image: a]
[image: result]
[image: expected]

Expected over Result zoomed in 
[image: expected vs result]

Comment: Open a ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org. Run your command with `-v verbose` added and capture log. Share full command and log there..

Comment: Thanks, Gyan,  http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8563

Comment: Workaround: `ffmpeg -y -i b.png -i a.png -filter_complex "[0:v]format=rgba[a];
    [1:v]format=rgba[b];
    [a][b]overlay=format=auto"  normal.png`

Comment: @llogan add it as the answer. Explained at trac.

Comment: @Gyan Added. Would be nice if auto was the default.

Comment: Yes, but at this stage, many scripts in use probably assume yuv420p output.

Comment: @Gyan Obviously, there is always the ever-present "scripts" argument, but I don't think that is reason enough.

Comment: Fine by me but good luck on the ML :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default pixel format for [overlay filte](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay)r is yuv420p. Use the `format` option in overlay to set it as `auto` or `rgb`.

```
ffmpeg -y -i b.png -i a.png -filter_complex "[0:v]format=rgba[a]; [1:v]format=rgba[b]; [a][b]overlay=format=auto" normal.png
```